# Modal height not increasing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a modal as given here below:

[image]

The modal has to be large enough to have the first text field and check button beside each other, and the second text field and check button beside each other. I tried to increase the height and width of the modal, but succeeded in increasing only the width. The height is becoming smaller, when trying to customise the modal size. Using `modal-lg` had the same effect. My code is given below:

```
<div id="addQueue" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog addqueue-modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add a Queue to your Desk</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                            <label for="queuename">Name your Queue: </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="queuename">
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" value="closedqueue">Create a Closed Queue; Open when ready</label>
                        </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <label for="queueinfo">Additional information about the Queue: </label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="queueinfo">
                            </div>
                            <span class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" value="tooltipdisplay">Display as tooltip when hovering over the Queue</label>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The relevant CSS is given below:

```
.addqueue-modal{

    width: 1000px;
    max-height: 1000px;
}
```

Does anyone know how I can fix my modal to have my text fields and checkboxes in the same lines as described earlier? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check Modal i.e. "<div id="addQueue" class="modal fade" role="dialog">" height once

Comment: @Srinu I did <div id="addQueue" class="modal fade addqueue-modal" role="dialog">. It made the modal size all right, but now the text fields and checkboxes are appearing one below the other.

Comment: Don't move class "addqueue-modal" to parent. try to write height for the parent i.e. "addQueue"

Comment: no,that didn't work..:(

Comment: overflow: hidden;

Comment: float: left; overflow: hidden;

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.addqueue-modal{
    width: 1000px;
    max-height: 1000px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: can you fiddle or pen it

Comment: I just added that overflow-y line to the CSS, the result is the same as before.